# ERROR on Populate RadAutoCompleteTextViewComponent

Tags: nativescript

I got the error bellow on trying to populate a RadAutoCompleteTextView.
Any hint in regard?

Many thanks in advance

```
@ViewChild("rankingsCtrl", { static: false }) rankingsCtrl: RadAutoCompleteTextViewComponent;


this.rankingsCtrl.autoCompleteTextView.insertTokenAtIndex(new TokenModel("Test",""), 0);


JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'addTokenModelAt' of undefined
JS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addTokenModelAt' of undefined
JS:     at RadAutoCompleteTextView.push.../node_modules/nativescript-ui-autocomplete/ui-autocomplete.js.RadAutoCompleteTextView.insertTokenAtIndex (file:///node_modules/nativescript-ui-autocomplete/ui-autocomplete.js:589:0)
```

Comment: When exactly you are calling `insertTokenAtIndex`?

Comment: Please find below the missing parts of the puzzle: this.rankingDaoService.findRankingsByPlayerId(this.idPlayer).then(
                    val => {
                        for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                            this.rankingsCtrl.autoCompleteTextView.insertTokenAtIndex(new TokenModel("Just Test",""), 0);
                        }
                    }
                );

Comment: And the UI XML part: <StackLayout class="input-field">
        <RadAutoCompleteTextView #rankingsCtrl [items]="dataItems" completionMode="Contains" layoutMode="Horizontal"
            displayMode="Tokens">
            <SuggestionView  >
                <ng-template  let-item="item">
                    <StackLayout >
                        <Label [text]="item.text" class="ranking-label"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ng-template>
            </SuggestionView>
        </RadAutoCompleteTextView>
    </StackLayout>

Comment: Still not what I was looking for. Need to know where exactly this code is called in your component. May be in onInit or click of a button like that...

Comment: Oh sorry for misunderstanding. It is the ngOnInit() of the component. Actually it's about modifying ([U]pdate part of the CRUD) the player data when I try to populate the player rankings with the already selected (on the [C]reation part) ones.

Comment: Try calling it in loaded event of the rad auto complete text view itself.

Comment: Manoj, MAN YOU SAVE MY DAY! Indeed doing what you suggest that do the trick. More specifically, may be help someone else, loading the tokens differently but ngOnInit,  in my case (loaded) event, solved my problem: <RadAutoCompleteTextView (loaded)="whenRankingsAreLoaded()" ...> of course the this.rankingsCtrl.autoCompleteTextView.insertTokenAtIndex(new TokenModel("Test",""), 0); was added on the whenRankingsAreLoaded() method instead of ngOnInit.

Comment: I also find a workaround in case you want to populate the list from ngOnInit. Setup a time out wrapping your code like this:  setTimeout(() => { ... }, 1); Where ... could be this.rankingsCtrl.autoCompleteTextView.insertTokenAtIndex(token), etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to access an element or it's methods upon ngOnInit as it's not guaranteed the underlaying nativeElement is created.

Try to use `loaded` event of the component which ensures the elements are created. A `timeout` may work but I wouldn't suggest it as it's not guaranteed all the time.

If you like to access multiple elements, then waiting for parent view's loaded event should be enough, all child elements should be created and ready for use by then.